# Can't build for release - Flutter, Xcode

Tags: ios, build, flutter

I have built a couple of Flutter apps using IntelliJ and xcode on a Mac server to build for ios release, and it has worked fine. Now I am suddenly having troubles building for release.

To test to see if it was something in my app, I just started a new app from scratch in IntelliJ on the server, configured the framework (including directing to the flutter install), and tested it out.

It builds and runs on the simulator just fine. But when I try to build for release ("flutter build ios" from command line) I get an error, which I will paste at the end of this message.

I have been trying for some time to figure out why I am getting the errors when building my app. Now even the default app seems broken.

Does the problem have something to do with the server?

Thank you.

The error message that I get when building for release (I gave the project a silly name, added an icon, and gave the app a build and version number, but otherwise it is an untouched flutter default app):

74-80-250-218:untitled userxxxxx$ flutter build ios

Building com.burrito.untitled for device (ios-release)...

Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team

in Xcode project: xxxxxxxxxx

Running Xcode build...

├─Building Dart code...                                    22.7s

├─Generating dSYM file...                                   0.2s

├─Stripping debug symbols...                                0.0s

├─Assembling Flutter resources...                           1.2s

└─Compiling, linking and signing...                         0.2s

Xcode build done.                                           26.2s

Failed to build iOS app

Error output from Xcode build:

↳

** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:

↳

In file included from

/Users/userxxxxxx/Desktop/untitled/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:5:

/Users/userxxxxxx/Desktop/untitled/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:8:

9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

#import

^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1 error generated.

In file included from

/Users/userxxxxx/Desktop/untitled/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:5:

/Users/userxxxxxx/Desktop/untitled/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:8:

9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

#import

^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1 error generated.

Encountered error while building for device.

Comment: If you using Xcode 10, you may need to change the Build System to Legacy one. Check Xcode>File>WorkSpace Setting>Build System

Comment: Sachin Vas - thank you for the suggestion, I have already tried that.

Comment: Well, after suffering for more than a week with this issue, I found an accidental solution. 

I ran "flutter build ios" from the command line without opening Xcode or IntelliJ to test the app before building. I had tested it on different days, and it would run once on the simulator, then never build again.
After successful build release, I opened Xcode and made an archive. I validated and uploaded the archive to App Store Connect, and loaded it into Testflight and tested. It worked.

Comment: The solution which you mentioned implies the build system changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try deleting the `ios` folder on the project and generate an iOS build again by running `flutter create --platforms=ios [PROJECT_PATH]`. That should generate an iOS project from your Flutter code. After that, run `flutter build ios` again.